# How to serialize Python dict to JSON

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary, typeerror

So I have some python dict that I want to serialize to JSON

```
{'someproperty': 0, 'anotherproperty': 'value', 'propertyobject': SomeObject(someproperty=0, anotherproperty=0)}
```

but `json.dumps` throws a `TypeError: SomeObject(someproperty=0, anotherproperty=0) is not JSON serializable`

So how can I serialize my python dict properly?

Comment: You cannot have object even SomeObject should be a json object. something like {'someproperty': 0, 'anotherproperty': 'value', 'SomeJson':{'someproperty':0, 'anotherproperty':0}}

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is, python doesn't know how to represent `SomeObject`

You can create a fallback like so:

```
import json

def dumper(obj):
    try:
        return obj.toJSON()
    except:
        return obj.__dict__

obj = {'someproperty': 0, 'anotherproperty': 'value', 'propertyobject': SomeObject(someproperty=0, anotherproperty=0)}

print json.dumps(obj, default=dumper, indent=2)
```

Comment: Is there a way I can return json data sorted by dictionary key?

Comment: @iDev yup, use sort_keys=True in json.dump

Answer (score 5):

**Python can serialize only the objects that is a built in data type.** 
In your case, "SomeObject" is a User defined type that Python cannot serialize. If you try to serialize any data type which is not json serializable, you get a TypeError "**TypeError:  is not JSON serializable**". So there should be an intermediate step that converts these non built in data types into Python built in serializable data structure (list, dict, number and string).

So let us convert your SomeObject into a python dictionary, since dictionary is the easiest way to represent your Object(as it has key/value pairs). You could just copy all your SomeObject instance attributes to a new dictionary and you are set!
**myDict = self.__dict__.copy()**
This *myDict* can now be the value of your "propertyobject".

After this step is when you convert dictionary to a string (JSON format, but it can be YAML, XML, CSV...) - for us it will be **jsonObj = JSON.dumps(finalDict)**

Last step is to write jsonObj string to a file on disk!